# Symfony 2.7 composer does not install doctrine-migrations-bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I Have installed Symfony 2.7 and trying to install `"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",` I do `composer update` to instal my newly added migration bundle in composer.jason but nothing gets installed instead composer prompts me with a message: `Nothing to install or update`. I tried googling any knows issues with the bundle but hit nothing. Any idea why this is happening...? thx

Comment: Its already installed please check in AppKernel.php. is it enabled or not.

Comment: It means you already had newly version installed.

Comment: Yep in normal sercostances I would agree that it has been already installed but the bundle is not in my vendor directory and when I add it to my Kenral it  comes up as undefined namespace, does not exists.